# Xcode 15.0: "expand macro" stays greyed out

Tags: swift, xcode, xcode15, swift-macro

“Expand Macro” stays gray even though I’ve seen the `@Observable` macro expanding earlier.

[image]

However when I manually trigger build error it does expand the location of the error. In this case I target macOS 13.5 that doesn't support `ObservationRegistrar`.

[image]

I tried to restart Xcode, try different macros, different projects and types of projects.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I believe you are missing `import Observation` at the top of your file

I ran into the same issue as it is not so straight forward that all the `@Observable` macros "work" in code, they just cant be expanded without importing first.
Seems like the compiler does not require the import, just Xcode.

Answer (score 1):

`@Observable` is only available in

iOS 17.0+
iPadOS 17.0+
macOS 14.0+
Mac Catalyst 17.0+
tvOS 17.0+
watchOS 10.0+
visionOS 1.0+ Beta

You cannot use it for macOS 13.5. I don't think any of the macros work below macOS 14.

Comment: If I put the correct compiler targets everything works fine, but I still cannot expand the macro